node_modules\ajv-keywords\dist\definitions\typeof.js
While running npm start am facing this issue
S C:\Users\Admin\Suganya Projects\Ecommerce\Ecommerce\frontend> npm start

frontend@0.1.0 start
react-scripts start

Cannot find module 'ajv/dist/compile/codegen'
Require stack:

C:\Users\Admin\Suganya Projects\Ecommerce\Ecommerce\frontend\node_modules\ajv-keywords\dist\definitions\typeof.js
C:\Users\Admin\Suganya Projects\Ecommerce\Ecommerce\frontend\node_modules\ajv-keywords\dist\keywords\typeof.js
C:\Users\Admin\Suganya Projects\Ecommerce\Ecommerce\frontend\node_modules\ajv-keywords\dist\keywords\index.js
C:\Users\Admin\Suganya Projects\Ecommerce\Ecommerce\frontend\node_modules\ajv-keywords\dist\index.js
C:\Users\Admin\Suganya Projects\Ecommerce\Ecommerce\frontend\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js
C:\Users\Admin\Suganya Projects\Ecommerce\Ecommerce\frontend\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\index.js
C:\Users\Admin\Suganya Projects\Ecommerce\Ecommerce\frontend\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\lib\Server.js
C:\Users\Admin\Suganya Projects\Ecommerce\Ecommerce\frontend\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js

S C:\Users\Admin\Suganya Projects\Ecommerce\Ecommerce\frontend> npm start

frontend@0.1.0 start
react-scripts start

Cannot find module 'ajv/dist/compile/codegen'
Require stack:

C:\Users\Admin\Suganya Projects\Ecommerce\Ecommerce\frontend\node_modules\ajv-keywords\dist\definitions\typeof.js
C:\Users\Admin\Suganya Projects\Ecommerce\Ecommerce\frontend\node_modules\ajv-keywords\dist\keywords\typeof.js
C:\Users\Admin\Suganya Projects\Ecommerce\Ecommerce\frontend\node_modules\ajv-keywords\dist\keywords\index.js
C:\Users\Admin\Suganya Projects\Ecommerce\Ecommerce\frontend\node_modules\ajv-keywords\dist\index.js
C:\Users\Admin\Suganya Projects\Ecommerce\Ecommerce\frontend\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js
C:\Users\Admin\Suganya Projects\Ecommerce\Ecommerce\frontend\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\index.js
C:\Users\Admin\Suganya Projects\Ecommerce\Ecommerce\frontend\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\lib\Server.js
C:\Users\Admin\Suganya Projects\Ecommerce\Ecommerce\frontend\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js


Please change the formatting of your question. It is recommended to put console output which describes the error/context into a codeblock with txt formatting (instead of using a bullet text list). Also you can quote the commands you entered into single back tick quotes like this npm start to make it easier for people to help

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
